# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

lo que pasa es que necesito realizar un ejercicio que me llene de una clase php o sea mostrarme una lista.

index.php

```
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="5">
        List
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Producto 1:
        <input type="hidden" name="cta" value="<?php echo $cta; ?>">
      </th>
      <td>
        <select id="list" class="form-control" name="list" required>
          <option value="">Select please...</option>
          <?php $ObjUtilidades->Select("prod_codigo, prod_descripcion","productos","prod_descripcion", "where prod_indicativo=1"); ?>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="listadd"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick='agregar_campos_kts()'>Add</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var contador0=1;
    function agregar_campos_kts()
    {
            contador0++;
            $('#cta_campos').val(contador0);

            $('<tr class="contra'+contador0+'"><td><p>Producto '+contador0+' </p></td>\n\
            <td colspan="3"><select  id="producto1" name="producto1" class="form-control">\n\
            <option value="">Select please... </option>\n\
    <?php $ObjUtilidades->Select("prod_codigo, prod_descripcion","productos", "prod_descripcion", "where prod_indicativo=1"); ?>\n\
            </select></td>\n\
                <td><p>Consumo</p></td>\n\
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="consumo'+contador0+'" name="consumo[]" required dir="rtl" ></td>\n\
                <td style="color:transparent;border:none;background:url(../img/deletered.png)  no-repeat;no-repeat;background-size:90% 60%;margin-top:3% 0% 0% 0%;">\n\
                <input type="button"  id="elimi'+contador0+'" class="eliminar"  value="'+contador0+'" ></td>\n\
            </tr>alert(contador)').appendTo( "#listadd" );

        $("input.eliminar").click(function()
            {
                var es=alert('Seguro que desea Eliminar');

                        var estu=$(this).attr("value");
                        $(".contra"+estu).remove();

            });

    }
    </script>
```

Listo, hasta hay bien, me muestra lo que es la lista...
Lista: Dato
       Dato y asi
Lo que quiero es que con el JavaScript al hacerlo me muestre la lista nuevamente... En el inspeccionar me aparece la lista y si se visualiza... Pero en el inspeccionar pero en la lista no. Dice el error: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

El error es claro, falta un parentesis pero revise el codigo y no tengo nada que falte cerrar...

Comment: Son necesarios los \n\ ?

Comment: el problema esta en la función `agregar_campos`.. tal como lo tienes imposible que funcione... empieza a separar el contenido.. de php..javascript y html

Comment: El problema viene hay, si no pongo ese php en ese javascript no me "mostraria" la lista, por tal motivo no se entonces como lograr que funcione; en la consola si me muestra los datos y todo... Obviamente si quito el PHP me funciona pero he hay mi problema ¿Como hago entonces? @aldanux

Comment: El codigo asi como esta y solo quitando la llamada a "*$ObjUtilidades->Select...*" no generar ningún error. Que es lo que devuele "$ObjUtilidades"? Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar tambien html final?

Comment: Podrías empezar a usar [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)... cuando presiones el botón `Add` haces la llamada vía ajax.. cual hace la consulta de la base de datos y el resultado lo devuelves al HTML... suena complicado pero no lo es.... hay un montón de ejemplos ahí fuera..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solucion al problema era que necesitaba la lista de ese codigo PHP al no poder usarla lo que hice fue ponerlo de este modo:

```
<tbody id="agrega">
                                 <tr>
                                    <td><label>Producto 1</label></td>
                                    <td id="listaproducto"><select  id='producto1' name='producto[]' class="form-control" value='<?php echo $producto1 ?>'>

                                    <option value="">Selecciona </option>
                                    <?php
                                          $ObjUtilidades->CargaSelectGeneral("prod_codigo, prod_descripcion","productos", $producto, "prod_descripcion", "where prod_indicativo=1");
                                     ?>
                                    </select>

                                    <td><label >&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Consumo&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp</label></td>
                                    <td id="listaconsumo"><input type="text" name="consumo[]" id="consumo1" placeholder="Ingrese cantidad a consumir" maxlength='100' class="form-control" size='3' value="<?php echo $consumo1?>"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
```

Ya despues simplemente lo que hice fue:

```
var contador0=1;

function agregar_campos_kts(){
    contador0++;
    $('#cta_campos').val(contador0);

    $('<tr class="contra'+contador0+'">\n\
    <th><p>Producto '+contador0+'</p></th><td id="producto'+contador0+'" ></td>\n\
    <th><p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Consumo&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp '+contador0+'</p></th>\n\
    <td id="consumo'+contador0+'"></td>\n\
    <td style="color:transparent;border:none;background:url(../img/deletered.png)  no-repeat;no-repeat;background-size:90% 60%;margin-top:3% 0% 0% 0%;">\
    <input type="button"  id="elimi'+contador0+'" class="eliminar"  value="'+contador0+'" ></td></tr>').appendTo("#agrega");

    $("#listaproducto").clone().appendTo("#producto"+contador0).addClass( "listkts" );

    $("#listaconsumo").clone().appendTo("#consumo"+contador0).addClass( "listkts" );

$("input.eliminar").click(function()
    {
        var es=alert('Seguro que desea Eliminar');

                var estu=$(this).attr("value");
                $(".contra"+estu).remove();

    });}
```

Se ve algo desordenado pero bueno, lo que hice fue usar un .clone() y para añadirle estilo a la lista e input hice fue poner un .addClass para el estilo y listo, con eso me funciono perfectamente, clonando la lista.

Bueno yo mismo me encontré la solución y aquí la comparto.

Answer (score 2):

cambia esto

```
<?php $ObjUtilidades->Select("prod_codigo, prod_descripcion","productos","prod_descripcion", "where prod_indicativo=1"); ?>
```

por esto

```
<?php $ObjUtilidades->Select("prod_codigo", "prod_descripcion","productos","prod_descripcion", "where prod_indicativo=1"); ?>
```

cerraste mal las comillas en prod_codigo

Un saludo

Comment: No cerré mal las comillas, esa parte de prod_codigo lo que hace es una consulta de PHP como ya había comentado, funcionaba eso bien, ya arregle el problema y posteare la solución.

Answer (score 0):

Dado que no puedo comentar porque soy nuevo.

Mi respuesta es que si deseas usar PHP dentro de javascript, hazlo al revés
Genera todo tu código javascript con php,

```
echo '<script></script>'
```

Aunque lo que yo recomiendo es usar AJAX para hacer peticiones desde javascript a php y solo renderizar.

Como bien dicen en los comentarios, hay muchos ejemplos de todo esto

Saludos

Comment: Si pero usarla de esa forma no me servia y me di cuenta porque igual dañaba el codigo y no eran compatibles lo que use fue el .clone() @Walter